# Find possible eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I need to find all eigenvalues of f, but I don't know how to start?
What is K=Z7 and f^3(v)=v means?
This is the question from past paper.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_7$ is the field with $7$ elements (which is unique up to isomorphism as $7$ is a prime).

So you calculute everything modulo 7. So for example $4\cdot 4=16\equiv 2$

Furthermore $f^3(v)= v$ means $f\circ f\circ f=f^3=id$ where $id$ is the identity.

Hence $f$ is for sure a zero of 
$$x^3-1=(x^2+x+1)(x-1)$$
so try to the zeroes of the polynomial.

As you have only finite many elements you can do this by checking every element.

As $2^2+2+1=7\equiv 0$, $2$ is another zero of $x^3-1$ hence

$$x^3-1=(x-2)\cdot (x-1)\cdot (x-4)$$

Comment: this is written very clearly

Comment: How can you get (x^3-1)? I am a little confused.

Comment: @Tom The minimal polynomial of a linear operator is the polynomial of smallest degree such that $p(f)=0$. As $f^3-id=0$ we know that the minimal polynomial must divide $x^3-1$. We already know that this is the minimal polynomial and furthermore $f$ will be diagonalizable.